# how do I include files in gitlab ci/cd?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a python pipeline that runs in Domino, and uses a number of .csv and .jar files that reside on the Domino file repository.  I am trying to run the same pipeline in Gitlab ci/cd, but I'm not sure how to upload or include the files into the gitlab ci/cd pipeline.  can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

just create a script that download the file from the domino repository

I dont know how domino works, but I think that is possible to download/retrieve the files from the api

Looking at the documentation, you can see some examples

https://docs.dominodatalab.com/en/4.2/reference/data/Basics_of_moving_data_over_a_network.html